# How do I fix my URL redirect, cloak and log visit python script?

Tags: python, flask, url, redirect, python-requests

Please forgive my English, it's not the best.

I have compiled a python script using requests and flask that redirects, cloaks urls and logs the visit for each URL address provided (or at least that is what it is meant to be doing...).

For each separate URL provided in a data.csv file, it will create a new txt file on the server named after the redirect path name, and log the details of each visit to that redirect url.

My issue is that is even though it seems to be working properly (I am running it on cpanel, using cPanel's python app setup), and it's not giving any errors - it is still not redirecting to the destination url, and doesn't log any visits.

**UPDATE:**

In the stderr log I get this error:
[UID:1566][760944] Child process with pid: 761215 was killed by signal: 15, core dump: 0......

Front-end now shows (probably caching issue):
Internal Server Error 500

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

## **The Code:**

*.HTACCESS*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $main.py [L]
```

*APP.PY*

```
import os
import datetime
import requests
from flask import Flask, request, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

# Load URL redirects from data.txt file


def load_redirects():
    redirects = {}
    with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            key, value = line.strip().split('|')
            redirects[key] = value
    return redirects

# Log visitor information to TXT file


def log_visitor(url, ip, city, country):
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    log_entry = f"{timestamp} | IP: {ip} | City: {city} | Country: {country}\n"
    with open(f"{url}.txt", 'a') as file:
        file.write(log_entry)

# Get visitor's IP address and geolocation


def get_visitor_info():
    ip = request.headers.get('X-Forwarded-For', request.remote_addr)
    response = requests.get(f"http://ip-api.com/json/{ip}")
    data = response.json()
    city = data.get('city', 'Unknown')
    country = data.get('country', 'Unknown')
    return ip, city, country

# Route for handling URL redirects


@app.route('/<path:url>')
def redirect_url(url):
    redirects = load_redirects()
    if url in redirects:
        ip, city, country = get_visitor_info()
        log_visitor(url, ip, city, country)
        return redirect(redirects[url])
    else:
        return "URL not found"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

*DATA.CSV*

```
Ebay|https://ebay.com/
Amazon|https://amazon/
```

Comment: "My issue is that it seems to be working" err, ok. Have you opened the dev console (F12) to see what's happening on the front end?

Comment: @roganjosh hi, yeah that is why I am posting my question =\ request passes w. status code 200. Just not redirecting or logging on server.

Comment: Probably not from the URL you expect. Put `print("Hello Daniel")` inside `def redirect_url(url):` and check your server log

Comment: @roganjosh stderr log:- [UID:1566][760944] Child process with pid: 761215 was killed by signal: 15, core dump: 0...... Front-end:- Internal Server Error 500